# Accessing Fill Color of rectangle inside DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, data-binding, datatemplate

Please go through my problem before marking it duplicate.

I am making a Windows Phone app in xaml c# VS2013.
I am consuming Web API in a longlistselector (because I want to allow user to select item like in listbox).

XAML

```
                    <phone:LongListSelector Margin="24,0" x:Name="Longlist" d:IsHidden="True" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GoalTemplate}"/>



<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="GoalTemplate">
        <Grid Width="432" Height="90" Margin="0,33,0,0">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="90" StrokeThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="4">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding rcolor, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="86" Margin="27,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="405" Foreground="{StaticResource FlatUI-Blue1}" FontSize="26.667"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  FontSize="14.667" Height="49" Foreground="{StaticResource FlatUI-Grey}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

XAML.CS Code

```
void Maths_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string uri = "http://localhost:1361/api/chore";
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(uri));
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s1, e1) =>
        {
            //var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HomeWork[]>(e1.Result.ToString());
            //MessageBox.Show(data.ToString());
            var hw = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HomeWork[]>(e1.Result.ToString());
            foreach (HomeWork c in hw)
            {
                if (c.Chore_Type == "Maths")
                {
                    result.Add(c);
                    // result is a List<HomeWork> to store only maths
                    // homework in longlistselector
                }

            }

            Longlist.ItemsSource = result;


        };
    }
```

Now my problem is
I have a rectangle which indicates priority of homework.
In the database i have priority column containing "Normal","medium", and "High" Priority.
And I want Rectangle's fill color to be blue, orange, and green respectively.
But I am not able to change the color of the rectangle with respect to its priority(that is consumed from Web API.

Kindly guide me how to access the rectangle in data template an apply if-else Clause or something to change the color based on priority.

Thank you,
Please Guide me.
If you donot understand, please inform so i can explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand in the HomeWork class you have a property called Priority of type Enum or string,

Do the following:

1: Bind the Rectangle Fill Color to that property with a converter:

```
   <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="90" StrokeThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="4">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
              <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Priority, Converter={StaticResource PriorityColorConverter}"/>
         </Rectangle.Fill>
   </Rectangle>
```

2: And now add a converter in the following way:

```
<Page...>
...
<Page.Resources>
 <Converters:PriorityColorConverter x:Key="PriorityColorConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

3: And Create that converter:

```
public class PriorityColorConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
       var priority = (Priorities)value;

        if (priority == Priorities.High)
            return Colors.Blue;
        else if (priority == Priorities.Medium)
            return Colors.Orange;
        else
            return Colors.Green;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Of course add in Page the xmlns namespace where you have created the converter.